Tags Without Usage Guidance?
Tags are quickly being created without usage guidance.  I hope that someone else has noticed. Should we allow tagging without being clear as to what a tag means?

For some of the recently created tags ([tag:lov], [tag:sz], lll) with no related question, that's an accident I take responsibility for. That happened while creating [tag:lenstra-lenstra-lovasz] and it's alias LLL (working except it's shown in lowercase) . I'll remove them as soon as I find how; or perhaps the system will self-heal. The question applies for several other tags, including [tag:hqc], [tag:blake3], [tag:blockchain] (that I think I created as part of a question asking what that is), [tag:gaussian-noise]

@fgrieu Some tags (such as blockchain) seem destined to encourage many off-topic questions, even if they have usage guidance. Looking at the tag 'cryptocurrency' over the last 30 days, only one question has been answered, and it related to using a bitcoin miner to break 2key 3DES. Most are closed/migrated as off-topic.

@ModalNest yes. In retrospect, creating [tag:blockchain] was a bad idea. Unfortunately, there is no way to delete it. However I can make it unused, and it will be much less visible.

I disagree, I don't think blockchain is a bad idea. First of all, I don't think tags will draw that many tourists here. And since blockchain is certainly a cryptographic protocol, I think it is on topic as well. Note that there is no generic blockchain related site at the moment, so generic questions won't be answered on any other sites either :(
